# Prove that $\{x_1,x_2\} $ is a L.I set of solutions to $x''+ax'+bx=0$ iff $W(x_1,x_2)\neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> **Question**.
>
> Prove that $\{x_1,x_2\} $ is a L.I set of solutions to $x''+ax'+bx=0$ iff $W(x_1,x_2)\neq 0$.

**Attempt**

Given statement is equivalent to

$$\{x_1,x_2\} \text { L.D} \iff W:=x_1x_2'-x_2x_1'=0.$$

Now:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1x_2'-x_2x_1'=0 &\iff \frac {x_1}{x_1'}=\frac {x_2}{x_2'}\iff\\
 \ln x_1 = \ln cx_2&\iff x_1=cx_2\iff\\
x_1-cx_2=0 &\iff \{x_1,x_2\} \text{ L.D}.
\end{align}
$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Why are you allowed to divide by $x_1', x_2'$?  What if they are zero?  This is the right idea, but you should be very careful with these deductions; for example, if $x_2=0$ and $x_1\neq 0$ then it is not the case that $x_1=cx_2$ for some $c$.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I missed those cases. Should I treat sepparately the cases: $x_1'\neq 0, x_2'\neq 0; x_1'=0, x_2'\neq 0; x_1'=0, x_2'=0$?